# ip-helper outside the helped network range

Tags: dhcp

On every vlan I have two ip ranges (for historical reasons). To PXE boot machines on these vlans I use ip helper/dhcp relay to relay requests onto the vlan where the dhcp server sits.

But the dhcp server only handles DHCP requests for one of the ip ranges (the one used as source address in the relayed dhcp message). How could I tell my dhcp server så accept dhcp requests for multiple subnets from one specific IP?

Comment: The answer to this question is the same as the answer to a [previous question](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/dhcp-relay-problem-on-interfaces-secondary-network).

Answer (score 1):

just try to gave your interface vlan two IPs

> #vlan 10
>    # int vlan 10
>    # ip add X.X.X.X M.M.M.M
>    # ip add Y.Y.Y.Y M.M.M.M secondary
>    # ip helper address *your DHCP server address*

so that DHCP sever will be able to give IP to hosts in rang of X.X.X.X M.M.M.M and in range of Y.Y.Y.Y M.M.M.M , but i'm not sure which host get which IP

`but it is better to configure two interface vlans instead of one with two ranges`

also make use of this link about [multiple range in same vlan](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11152746/using-ip-helper-address-vlan-three-subnets)

also i'm not understand how you put two ranges in one vlan

Comment: do not try to understand it. I have seen worse... segmenting VLAN1 into 10 /24 subnets.... :)

Comment: Yes, I already know you guys hate having multiple subnets on the same vlan, but could you for once just ignore that and concentrate on the question. The problem is that the DHCP-server just gives out leases on the same subnet as the src address from the helper. Making it i impossible to PXE-boot from the secondary ip range.

Comment: This is how DHCP relay is supposed to work.  How else could it work out which subnet you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Cisco you could use static mac mapping and `ip dhcp smart-relay`.  This will send 3 requests from the primary interface address, and if the DHCP server doesn't respond (i.e. the MAC isn't in the pool for than subnet on the server), then it will switch the giaddr in the relay request to the secondary address.

If you're not on Cisco, well, this is how DHCP relay is supposed to work.

You **could** create a large supernet on the DHCP server that encompasses both ranges and then use static MAC mappings for the hosts you want on the second range.

Personally though, rather than perpetuating bad designs with filthy hacks I would concentrate on removing legacy crap from your network ; )

Comment: Haha. We are removing them.